# Prove $x^4-18x^2+36x-27$ can never be a nonzero square rational when $x$ is rational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove $x^4-18x^2+36x-27$ can never be a square rational (excluding 0), when x is rational

I have tried to use modulus, but didn't get anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Square integer? Square rational?

Comment: Sorry, square rational

Comment: I tried bounding it between consecutive squares as well, but that did't work

Comment: Try factoring the expression, that may help!

Comment: I did factorise it into $\left(x-3\right)\left(x^3+3x^2-9x+9\right)$

Comment: So for $x=3$ the value is $0=0^2$, a square.

Comment: Excluding the value $0$, sorry again

Comment: Try to factor the factor on the right side, then. I don't think you will get very far, and that might help you with your proof. Also, welcome to the forum!

Comment: You cannot simplify the right side any further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $y^2=x^4-18x^2+36x-27$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve $w^2=z^3-432$, with $x=\frac{w-36}{2(z-12)}$. This curve has rank $0$ and torsion group $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, hence only two rational points $(z,w)=(12,\pm36)$. If we substitute these points into the formula for $x$, the positive $w$ gives the excluded $x=3$ solution and the negative $w$ incurs a division by zero. Hence $x^4-18x^2+36x-27$ can never be a nonzero rational square for rational $x$.

Answer (score -2):

Say $x^4-18*x^2+36*x-27 = n^2$

The polynomial factors up

$(x-3)*(x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9) = n^2$

It means that if $x-3$ is a perfect square, then $x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9
$ is also a perfect square or both aren't perfect square

Just like $36=9×4=12×3$

If  $x-3$ is not a perfect square, then polynomial $x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9$ is not also a perfect, therefore it must factor up further, Just like $36=12×3=4×3×3$

But $x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9$ does not factor

It doesn't factor as supposed, it has to factor into $(x-3)*(x-a)^2$ in my definition, but there's no value of $a$ to fix this therefore $x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9$ does not factor to $(x-3)*(x-a)^2$

Say $x-3 = k^2$, $x = 3+k^2$

$(3+k^2)^3+3*(3+k^2)^2-9*(3+k^2)+9 = (n/k)^2$

$k^6+12*k^4+36*k^2+36 = (n/k)^2$

$k^2*(k^2+6)^2+36 = (n/k)^2$

$(k\cdot(k^2+6))^2 + 6^2 = (n/k)^2$

It's easy to see that no integer $k$ exist to that make this a perfect square

Therefore $x^4-18*x^2+36*x-27$ is not a perfect square

Comment: The fact that the polynomial $x^3+3x^2-9x+9$ doesn't factor does not imply that its values cannot individually factor.

Comment: I do not follow the argument from the penultimate to the final line, and I also agree that just because $x^3+3x^2-9x+9$ does not factorise doesn't mean that its values cannot factor individually.

Comment: It doesn't factor as supposed, it has to factor into $(x-3)*(x-a)^2$ in my definition, but there's no value of $a$ to fix this therefore $x^3+3*x^2-9*x+9$ does not factor to $(x-3)*(x-a)^2$

Comment: I dont think the logic is correct, a polynomial does not have to factor to a  polynomial^2, in order to have square solutions (ie x^3 +1), which is what I think your proof is implying.

Comment: Am not saying it must factor to a polynomial^2, I'm just saying it factors $x^3+1 = (x+1)*(x^2-x+1)$, knowing that it factors gives me a definition I'll use against it.... try re-reading my proof