# The image of the point at infinity under birational equivalence from an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry

To find rational points on the curve $C:y^2=P(x)$ where $P$ is a cubic or quartic with rational coefficients and no repeated roots, I can derive a birational equivalence between it and an elliptic curve $E$, and work with the elliptic curve. For example, $y^2=x^4-18x^2+36x-27$ is birationally equivalent to $w^2=z^3-432$ with $x=\frac{w-36}{2(z-12)}$ and $y=x^2-3-\frac z2$.

However, transforming points through birational equivalences may be a little tricky. For example, if the circle is parametrised as $x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},y=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, the point at infinity ($t=\infty$) corresponds to the finite point $(0,-1)$. This question is about the genus-$1$ case.

> If $E$ is in Weierstrass normal form and hence has the point at infinity $\mathcal O$ that serves as the identity of its Mordell–Weil group, do I need to consider $\mathcal O$ when transforming rational points on $E$ back to $C$? If so, what will $\mathcal O$ map to, given the map?

I was left with this question after editing [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3627299/357390) to a question that asked for all rational points on $y^2=x^4-18x^2+36x-27$. I was a little worried that I might have missed a few details, because I did not consider $\mathcal O$.

Comment: Is it your map base point free in homogenous coordinates? You should probably still consider it, but at least in that case it's easy to work with.

Comment: @TokenToucan The point at infinity is, in homogeneous coordinates, $[0:1:0]$. I have no need for the homogeneous formulation, just the image of it.

Comment: Yes I know what a point at infinity is, the point being that if you write your map in homogenous coordinates and infinity is not in the base locus, it is very easy to see what its image is and if that image is an extra rational point.

Comment: @TokenToucan You should write an answer detailing how to do that, in terms of the Weierstrass normal form of $C$ and the given birational equivalence.

Comment: What is the $y$-coordinate of your map? You've given $x$ in terms of $z$ and $w$, but in order to specify a map $E \to C$ you need to say what the second coordinate is: $(z,w) \mapsto (x,y) = \left(\frac{w-36}{2(z-12)}, ?\right)$.

Comment: Anyway, if I've guessed your map correctly, $(0:1:0)$ maps to $(3:0:1)$, i.e., $\infty$ maps to $(3,0)$.

Comment: @RichardD.James In this case, $y=x^2-3-\frac z2$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I think there's something wrong with the map you've proposed. If I evaluate your proposed definitions for $x$ and $y$ at the point $(12,36) \in E$, I get $(-1/2, -83/4)$, which is not a point on $C$.

Comment: @RichardD.James I think you should be able to work out the map yourself. I used [these equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592599/357390) to derive the map, and you should be able to use them too.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem: I reversed $z$ and $w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if these are the same maps that you found, but we have rational maps
\begin{align*}
\varphi: C &\dashrightarrow E\\
(x,y) &\mapsto \left(\frac{12x}{x-3}, -\frac{36y}{(x-3)^2}\right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\psi: E &\dashrightarrow C\\
(z,w) &\mapsto \left(\frac{3z}{z-12}, -\frac{36w}{(z-12)^2} \right)
\end{align*}
that are mutually inverse where they are defined. To compute $\psi(\infty)$, we change coordinates to a chart containing $\infty$. Homogenizing the equations for $C$ and $E$, we have
\begin{align*}
C: Y^2 Z^2 = X^4 - 18X^2 Z^2 + 36 X Z^3 - 27 Z^4
\end{align*}
where $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$ on the affine open where $Z \neq 0$, and
\begin{align*}
E: U^2 V = T^3 - 432 V^3
\end{align*}
where $z = T/V$ and $w = U/V$ on the affine open where $V \neq 0$. The homogenized version of $\psi$ is
$$
\psi = (3T(T-12V) : -36UV : (T-12V)^2) \, .
$$
The affine open where $U \neq 0$ contains the point $\infty = (0 : 1 : 0)$, so we move to this chart with coordinates $t = T/U$ and $v = V/U$. In this chart, $E$ is given by
\begin{align} \label{eqn:tv} \tag{1}
E: v = t^3 - 432 v^3 \, ,
\end{align}
the point $(0:1:0)$ is $(t,v) = (0,0)$, and $\psi$ becomes
$$
\psi = \left(3t(t-12v) : -36v : (t - 12v)^2 \right) \, .
$$
From (\ref{eqn:tv}) we see that $v=0$ is the tangent line to $E$ at $(0,0)$ and $v$ vanishes to order $3$. Then $t=0$ intersects transversely at $(0,0)$, so $t$ is a uniformizer, i.e., it vanishes to order $1$. Multiplying the expression for $\psi$ by $1/t^2$, we have
\begin{align*}
\psi &= \left(3 \frac{t-12v}{t} : -36 \frac{v}{t^2} : \frac{(t - 12v)^2}{t^2} \right) = \left(3\left(1 - 12\frac{v}{t}\right) : -36 \frac{v}{t^2} : \left(1 - 12 \frac{v}{t} \right)^2 \right) \, .
\end{align*}
Since $v$ vanishes to order $3$ at $(0,0)$ and $t$ only vanishes to order $1$, then this expression shows that
$$
\psi(0,0) = (3 : 0 : 1) \, .
$$
(One can also use (\ref{eqn:tv}) to see directly that $v/t$ vanishes at $(0,0)$:
$$
\frac{v}{t} \cdot \frac{t^2}{t^2} = \frac{t^2 v}{t^3} = \frac{t^2 v}{v + 432 v^3} = \frac{t^2}{1 + 432v^2}. )
$$
Thus $\psi(0:1:0) = (3:0:1)$, or in terms of the original affine coordinates, $\psi(\infty) = (3,0)$.